# Problema ao adicionar uma data em um índice de array

Tags: php, array

Estou passando uma data para dentro de um índice de um `Array`. Conforme vai sendo executado o looping, este `Array` vai sendo alimentado. O índice também é gerado através deste looping.
Porém, ao printar o índice, exibe apenas 1 caracter (como se estivesse "fragmentado" dentro do `Array`). Creio que é um erro simples, porém, estou me batendo por não ter passado por isto ainda.

```
$pcb_data = array();
while($r = $DB->fetchArray($result)){  
    $pcb_cmb_id = $r['pcb_cmb_id'];


    $pcb_data[$pcb_cmb_id] = date("d/m/Y",  strtotime($r['pcb_data']));
}
```

Se eu imprimir `$pcb_data[4]`, por exemplo, ele exibirá "2", ao invés de uma data (ex: 12/12/1988).

Obs: Cortei o código do while pq o restante das informações não possuem relevância, neste caso.

Alguém pode me ajudar, por favor?

Comment: De um `print_($pcb_data)`; depois do while, coloca nos comentários depois

Comment: Foi constatado que a variável do array estava sendo sobrescrita por outra informação, provavelmente criada para testes anteriores...foi removida esta informação e funcionou corretamente...Obrigado pelo auxílio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tentei replicar o mesmo erro mas sem sucesso, veja :

```
<?php 
$pcb_data = array();
$i = 0;

while($i < 2){                          
  $pcb_data[$i] = date("d/m/Y",  strtotime('2000-10-10'));
  $i++;
}
```

Saída

```
Array
(
  [0] => 10/10/2000
  [1] => 10/10/2000
)
```

obs: Tentei emular em diferentes versões do PHP [aqui](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/)

Os dados que estão vindo do banco estão corretos ?

Esse índice que você acessou realmente possui essa regra ?

Tem algum log ou algum erro sendo exibido ?

Comment: Foi constatado que a variável do array estava sendo sobrescrita por outra informação, provavelmente criada para testes anteriores...foi removida esta informação e funcionou corretamente...Obrigado pelo auxílio.

Answer (score 1):

Tente isso, acho que vai descobrir onde está ocorrendo o problema:

```
function formatDate($data) {
   return implode('-',array_reverse(explode("-", $data)));
}

$pcb_data = array();

while($r = $DB->fetchArray($result)){  
    $pcb_cmb_id = $r['pcb_cmb_id'];
    $pcb_data[] = array(
            'id'  => $r['pcb_cmb_id'],
            'data'=>  formatDate($r['pcb_data'])
           ); 
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($pcb_data);
```

Comment: Foi constatado que a variável do array estava sendo sobrescrita por outra informação, provavelmente criada para testes anteriores...foi removida esta informação e funcionou corretamente...Obrigado pelo auxílio.

Answer (score -1):

```
$pcb_data = array();
while($r = $DB->fetchArray($result)){
    $pcb_data[$r['pcb_cmb_id']] = date("d/m/Y",  strtotime($r['pcb_data']));
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($pcb_data);
echo '<pre>';
```

Não há necessidade de criar variáveis para tudo. Já coloca direto dentro da chave do array e seu valor.